# Finding out the ContentType of a Image from the byte[]

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to find out what the ContentType of an image is from only the original bytes?

At the moment I have a database column that stores only the byte[], which I use to display an image on a web page.

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes);
Image image = Image.FromStream(ms);
image.Save(context.HttpContext.Response.OutputStream, <--ContentType-->);
```

I could of course just save the ContentType in another column in the table, but just wondered if there was another way e.g. maybe .Net has a way to interrogate the data to get the type.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Check out this [file signatures table](http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html).

Comment: Cheers for the link. I did some searching, now I know what to look for and this does appear the way to go.

Comment: I have put a working version of the code below, based on your idea.

Answer (score 15):

File/magic signatures was the way to go. Below is the working version of the code.

Ref: [Stackoverflow - Getting image dimensions without reading the entire file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111345/getting-image-dimensions-without-reading-the-entire-file)

```
ImageFormat contentType = ImageHelper.GetContentType(this.imageBytes);

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(this.imageBytes);
Image image = Image.FromStream(ms);
image.Save(context.HttpContext.Response.OutputStream, contentType);
```

And then the helper class:

```
public static class ImageHelper
{
    public static ImageFormat GetContentType(byte[] imageBytes)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes);

        using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(ms))
        {
            int maxMagicBytesLength = imageFormatDecoders.Keys.OrderByDescending(x => x.Length).First().Length;

            byte[] magicBytes = new byte[maxMagicBytesLength];

            for (int i = 0; i < maxMagicBytesLength; i += 1)
            {
                magicBytes[i] = br.ReadByte();

                foreach (var kvPair in imageFormatDecoders)
                {
                    if (magicBytes.StartsWith(kvPair.Key))
                    {
                        return kvPair.Value;
                    }
                }
            }

            throw new ArgumentException("Could not recognise image format", "binaryReader");
        }
    }

    private static bool StartsWith(this byte[] thisBytes, byte[] thatBytes)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < thatBytes.Length; i += 1)
        {
            if (thisBytes[i] != thatBytes[i])
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static Dictionary<byte[], ImageFormat> imageFormatDecoders = new Dictionary<byte[], ImageFormat>()
    {
        { new byte[]{ 0x42, 0x4D }, ImageFormat.Bmp},
        { new byte[]{ 0x47, 0x49, 0x46, 0x38, 0x37, 0x61 }, ImageFormat.Gif },
        { new byte[]{ 0x47, 0x49, 0x46, 0x38, 0x39, 0x61 }, ImageFormat.Gif },
        { new byte[]{ 0x89, 0x50, 0x4E, 0x47, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x1A, 0x0A }, ImageFormat.Png },
        { new byte[]{ 0xff, 0xd8 }, ImageFormat.Jpeg },
    };
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a reason your loops increment with "i += 1" instead of "i++"?

Comment: I adapted the code from another Stackoverflow question/answer (mentioned above). The code has since changed as I also understand i++ more than i +=1.

Comment: @Portman, personal styles and preferences. Some people think `i++` is clearer, others think that it is less "best practice". See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/971312/why-avoid-increment-and-decrement-operators-in-javascript

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me, `ms` being the memorystream. The downside is that it has to load the image.

```
Dim fmt As System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat
Dim content As String

Using bmp As New Drawing.Bitmap(ms)
    fmt = bmp.RawFormat
End Using

Select Case fmt.Guid
    Case Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp.Guid
        content = "image/x-ms-bmp"

    Case Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg.Guid
        content = "image/jpeg"

    Case Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif.Guid
        content = "image/gif"

    Case Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png.Guid
        content = "image/png"

    Case Else
        content = "application/octet-stream"

End Select
```

Answer (score 4):

Rewrote the method of Nick Clarke a bit using Linq:

```
public class Program
{
   public static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      byte[] byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:/users/Alexander/image.jpg");
      ImagePartType type = byteArray.GetImageType();
   }
}


public static class ImageHelper
{
    public static ImagePartType GetImageType(this byte[] imageBytes)
    {
        foreach(var imageType in imageFormatDecoders)
        {
            if (imageType.Key.SequenceEqual(imageBytes.Take(imageType.Key.Length)))
                return imageType.Value;
        }

        throw new ArgumentException("Imagetype is unknown!");
    }

    private static Dictionary<byte[], ImagePartType> imageFormatDecoders 
                     = new Dictionary<byte[], ImagePartType>()
    {
       { new byte[]{ 0x42, 0x4D }, ImagePartType.Bmp},
       { new byte[]{ 0x47, 0x49, 0x46, 0x38, 0x37, 0x61 }, ImagePartType.Gif },
       { new byte[]{ 0x47, 0x49, 0x46, 0x38, 0x39, 0x61 }, ImagePartType.Gif },
       { new byte[]{ 0x89, 0x50, 0x4E, 0x47, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x1A, 0x0A }, ImagePartType.Png },
       { new byte[]{ 0xff, 0xd8 }, ImagePartType.Jpeg }
    };
}
```

I used `ImagePartType` because I'm working with Open XML SDK at the moment, but just change the type in the dictionary :)

Answer (score 1):

There's no standard way to detect content type from a stream built-in .NET. You could implement your own algorithm that could achieve this for some [well-known](http://www.mikekunz.com/image_file_header.html) image formats by reading the first few bytes and trying to match the format.

Answer (score 0):

Does the [`RawFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.rawformat.aspx) property work for you?

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes);
Image image = Image.FromStream(ms);
image.Save(context.HttpContext.Response.OutputStream, image.RawFormat);
```

Comment: RawFormat seems to work for jpeg and gif but not png. For a test I also tried hardcoding it to jpeg and this worked the same (for all and not png),  I guess .Net applies more logic to png.

Comment: From other examples I have seen RawFormat appears to only work when the image was loaded from the filesystem and not created via bytes (db column).