# How can i get resized image's new dimension with ImageResizer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image-processing, image-resizing

How can i get image's new dimension when it's resized. Imagesizer doesn't return resized image 's new dimension? Should i take it as this link? [How to get the image dimension from the file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6455979/how-to-get-the-image-dimensions-from-the-file-name)

```
        ImageJob imageJob = new ImageResizer.ImageJob(file, "~/uploads/prods/<guid>.<ext>", new ImageResizer.ResizeSettings(
                    "width=700;quality=100;format=jpg;mode=max"));
        imageJob.CreateParentDirectory = true; //Auto-create the uploads directory.

        //i need new height value for image
        imageJob.Build();
```

Answer (score 0):

ImageResizer has [source.width and source.height](http://documentation.imageresizing.net/doxygen/class_image_resizer_1_1_image_job.html) properties which you can request after the image is resized:

```
ImageResizer.ImageJob i = new ImageResizer.ImageJob(filename, 
    new string[] { "source.width", "source.height" });
i.Build();

int width = Convert.ToInt32(i.ResultInfo["source.width"]);
int height = Convert.ToInt32(i.ResultInfo["source.height"]);
```

Comment: I believe many would consider this a much better answer if it explained what the code was doing.