# How to get dimensions of images in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook-opengraph

I have a website with articles and pages having images. For sharing purposes, I need to get the dimensions of images for open graph meta property. The images are saved in a folder in my account.

Please tell me how can I get the dimensions of an image in my application folder.

Comment: have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6455979/how-to-get-the-image-dimension-from-the-file-name)? I think is kinda duplicate

Comment: Just load the images using the appropiate class constructor, and access their Width and Height properties?

Comment: @IoanaStoian searched but couldn't find this ....thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
using (var bmp = Image.FromFile(@"path_to_image"))
{
    var width = bmp.Width;
    var height = bmp.Height;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll load the image in, and access its width and height properties.

I suppose you'd like to see some code? Maybe in future post the code you have tried - and don't expect anyone to do it for you.

But here i am contradicting myself, you'll need something like this:

```
System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("the/path/to/your/image.jpg");
// you then access properties like so:
image.Width;
image.Height;
```