# Remote image size without downloading

Tags: ios, ios4, uiimage

Using Obj-c / Cocoa-touch, I'm trying to get the image size of a list of images but I don't  want to download them.
Is there some easy way to do it? I found some solutions in other languages like [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111345/getting-image-dimensions-without-reading-the-entire-file) but I'm looking for a easier way.

Thanks

Comment: image dimensions (width/height)? or image file size?

Answer (score 7):

Here is a UIImage category I use for this. It is based on [fastimage](https://github.com/sdsykes/fastimage). One major warning is the NSURLConnectionDelegate is set to the NSURL itself and this may cause clashes in certain situations. This isn't complete yet (file URL's are ignored for example...) but you can see where it is going.

Header:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

typedef void (^UIImageSizeRequestCompleted) (NSURL* imgURL, CGSize size);

@interface UIImage (RemoteSize)

+ (void) requestSizeFor: (NSURL*) imgURL completion: (UIImageSizeRequestCompleted) completion;

@end
```

Source:

```
#import "UIImage+RemoteSize.h"

#import <objc/runtime.h>

static char *kSizeRequestDataKey = "NSURL.sizeRequestData";
static char *kSizeRequestTypeKey = "NSURL.sizeRequestType";
static char *kSizeRequestCompletionKey = "NSURL.sizeRequestCompletion";

typedef uint32_t dword;

@interface NSURL (RemoteSize)
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableData* sizeRequestData;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* sizeRequestType;
@property (nonatomic, copy) UIImageSizeRequestCompleted sizeRequestCompletion;
@end

@implementation NSURL (RemoteSize)

- (void) setSizeRequestCompletion: (UIImageSizeRequestCompleted) block {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &kSizeRequestCompletionKey, block, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY);
}

- (UIImageSizeRequestCompleted) sizeRequestCompletion {
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &kSizeRequestCompletionKey);
}

- (void) setSizeRequestData:(NSMutableData *)sizeRequestData {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &kSizeRequestDataKey, sizeRequestData, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
}

- (NSMutableData*) sizeRequestData {
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &kSizeRequestDataKey);
}

- (void) setSizeRequestType:(NSString *)sizeRequestType {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &kSizeRequestTypeKey, sizeRequestType, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
}

- (NSString*) sizeRequestType {
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &kSizeRequestTypeKey);
}

#pragma mark - NSURLConnectionDelegate
- (void) connection: (NSURLConnection*) connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    [self.sizeRequestData setLength: 0];    //Redirected => reset data
}

- (void) connection: (NSURLConnection*) connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    NSMutableData* receivedData = self.sizeRequestData;

    if( !receivedData ) {
        receivedData = [NSMutableData data];
        self.sizeRequestData = receivedData;
    }

    [receivedData appendData: data];

    //Parse metadata
    const unsigned char* cString = [receivedData bytes];
    const NSInteger length = [receivedData length];

    const char pngSignature[8] = {137, 80, 78, 71, 13, 10, 26, 10};
    const char bmpSignature[2] = {66, 77};
    const char gifSignature[2] = {71, 73}; 
    const char jpgSignature[2] = {255, 216};

    if(!self.sizeRequestType ) {
        if( memcmp(pngSignature, cString, 8) == 0 ) {
            self.sizeRequestType = @"PNG";
        }
        else if( memcmp(bmpSignature, cString, 2) == 0 ) {
            self.sizeRequestType = @"BMP";
        }
        else if( memcmp(jpgSignature, cString, 2) == 0 ) {
            self.sizeRequestType = @"JPG";
        }
        else if( memcmp(gifSignature, cString, 2) == 0 ) {
            self.sizeRequestType = @"GIF";
        }
    }

    if( [self.sizeRequestType isEqualToString: @"PNG"] ) {
        char type[5];
        int offset = 8;

        dword chunkSize = 0;
        int chunkSizeSize = sizeof(chunkSize);

        if( offset+chunkSizeSize > length ) 
            return;

        memcpy(&chunkSize, cString+offset, chunkSizeSize);
        chunkSize = OSSwapInt32(chunkSize);
        offset += chunkSizeSize;

        if( offset + chunkSize > length ) 
            return;

        memcpy(&type, cString+offset, 4); type[4]='\0';
        offset += 4;

        if( strcmp(type, "IHDR") == 0 ) {   //Should always be first
            dword width = 0, height = 0;
            memcpy(&width, cString+offset, 4);
            offset += 4;
            width = OSSwapInt32(width);

            memcpy(&height, cString+offset, 4);
            offset += 4;
            height = OSSwapInt32(height);

            if( self.sizeRequestCompletion ) {
                self.sizeRequestCompletion(self, CGSizeMake(width, height));
            }

            self.sizeRequestCompletion = nil;

            [connection cancel];
        }
    }
    else if( [self.sizeRequestType isEqualToString: @"BMP"] ) {
        int offset = 18;
        dword width = 0, height = 0;
        memcpy(&width, cString+offset, 4);
        offset += 4;

        memcpy(&height, cString+offset, 4);
        offset += 4;

        if( self.sizeRequestCompletion ) {
            self.sizeRequestCompletion(self, CGSizeMake(width, height));
        }

        self.sizeRequestCompletion = nil;

        [connection cancel];
    }
    else if( [self.sizeRequestType isEqualToString: @"JPG"] ) {
        int offset = 4;
        dword block_length = cString[offset]*256 + cString[offset+1];

        while (offset<length) {
            offset += block_length;

            if( offset >= length )
                break;
            if( cString[offset] != 0xFF )
                break;
            if( cString[offset+1] == 0xC0 ||
                cString[offset+1] == 0xC1 ||
                cString[offset+1] == 0xC2 ||
                cString[offset+1] == 0xC3 ||
                cString[offset+1] == 0xC5 ||
                cString[offset+1] == 0xC6 ||
                cString[offset+1] == 0xC7 ||
                cString[offset+1] == 0xC9 ||
                cString[offset+1] == 0xCA ||
                cString[offset+1] == 0xCB ||
                cString[offset+1] == 0xCD ||
                cString[offset+1] == 0xCE ||
                cString[offset+1] == 0xCF ) {

                dword width = 0, height = 0;

                height = cString[offset+5]*256 + cString[offset+6];
                width = cString[offset+7]*256 + cString[offset+8];

                if( self.sizeRequestCompletion ) {
                    self.sizeRequestCompletion(self, CGSizeMake(width, height));
                }

                self.sizeRequestCompletion = nil;

                [connection cancel];

            }
            else {
                offset += 2;
                block_length = cString[offset]*256 + cString[offset+1];
            }

        }
    }
    else if( [self.sizeRequestType isEqualToString: @"GIF"] ) {
        int offset = 6;
        dword width = 0, height = 0;
        memcpy(&width, cString+offset, 2);
        offset += 2;

        memcpy(&height, cString+offset, 2);
        offset += 2;

        if( self.sizeRequestCompletion ) {
            self.sizeRequestCompletion(self, CGSizeMake(width, height));
        }

        self.sizeRequestCompletion = nil;

        [connection cancel];
    }
}

- (void) connection: (NSURLConnection*) connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    if( self.sizeRequestCompletion ) 
        self.sizeRequestCompletion(self, CGSizeZero);
}

- (NSCachedURLResponse *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willCacheResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse *)cachedResponse {
    return cachedResponse;
}

- (void) connectionDidFinishLoading: (NSURLConnection *)connection {
    // Basically, we failed to obtain the image size using metadata and the
    // entire image was downloaded...

    if(!self.sizeRequestData.length) {
        self.sizeRequestData = nil;
    }
    else {
        //Try parse to UIImage
        UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData: self.sizeRequestData];

        if( self.sizeRequestCompletion && image) {
            self.sizeRequestCompletion(self, [image size]);
            return;
        }
    }

    self.sizeRequestCompletion(self, CGSizeZero);
}

@end

@implementation UIImage (RemoteSize)

+ (void) requestSizeFor: (NSURL*) imgURL completion: (UIImageSizeRequestCompleted) completion {

    if( [imgURL isFileURL] ) {
        //Load from file stream
    }
    else {
        imgURL.sizeRequestCompletion = completion;

        NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: imgURL];
        NSURLConnection* conn = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest: request delegate: imgURL];
        [conn scheduleInRunLoop: [NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        [conn start];
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get just the size of the image file you can use a NSUrlConnection to request just the headers from the HTTP server (without downloading the image file) and then extract the Content-Length: from the headers to get the file size.  Use the expectedContentLength method in the [NSURLResponse](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLResponse_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLResponse/expectedContentLength) class, see [the doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLResponse_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLResponse/expectedContentLength) for more details.  It's still not easy.

Comment: To do that I can use the ASIHTTPRequest. I meant image dimensions and not size, sorry