# How to identify whether response coming from server is pdf or url or image?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In my app, when I send request to server either I will get url or pdf or image in response and based on that I will display the result (url->webview, image->imageview etc).But I do not know how to identify whether the response is url or pdf or image?

Please anyone know how I can achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Using the `content-type` in the HTTP response?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you do use NSURLConnection to download your file. So, implement this delegate method ...

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
```

... cast *response* to *NSHTTPURLResponse* and get *Content-Type* value from *allHeaderFields*.

But it depends what do you really use to download your files. If you do use another class/framework/..., you get an idea.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you to use UIWebview for both case either it is PDF or image url from server.

```
[imgwebVw loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strImgURL]]];
```

Comment: UIWebView s*cks ... Slow, bloated, ... :)

Comment: Use uiwebview Delegate methods...UiwebviewDidStartLoad/UiwebviewDidfinishLoad to show a uiactivity indicator while content is loading from server url.

Comment: You mean to say I can use uiwebview to load image, pdf and url?I do not need to find out whether response is image, pdf or url?[imgwebVw loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strImgURL]]]; will work for all three?

Comment: if you are getting a server url for all cases either pdf url or image url or other content url, it will works for all on uiwebview method 
[imgwebVw loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strImgURL]]]; just pass the url in the method.

Answer (score 0):

If you really must do this you can read the file headers but I wouldn't suggest it. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7164435/remote-image-size-without-downloading/10754296#10754296) is a category I wrote to get the size of a remote image, you can adapt it to detect if the file is indeed an image or not. And you can do similar stream parsing to search for the PDF Header: %PDF-1.0 etc. Otherwise you would assume it is a url.