# Know the size of a image in iOS before downloading it

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remote image size without downloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7164435/remote-image-size-without-downloading)

I have some tables,views, etc that shows images that are on remote URLs. In order to make the app more fluid, all the images are being downloaded asynchronously.

In that context, I need to know the width/height of an image without downloading it  in order to correctly set heights to the table rows and views that are one behind the other (like Pinterest gui).

Does anyone know how to do that?

Thanks?

Comment: Duplicating..http://stackoverflow.com/a/10754296/790794

Answer (score 0):

You should download the image and check it's size before displaying it. Or limit it's size and shrink it to fit your predetermined view height.

Answer (score 0):

Download image and change size of `UITableViewCell` and other `UIView's` after you get the `UIImage's` size.