# Get Image Width and Height without creating Bitmap Object

Tags: c#, .net, image, gdi+

I want to get the Height and Width of an Image.Currently what im doing is

```
Bitmap b=new Bitmap(path);
w=b.width;h=b.height;
```

Is there a better way to do it without creating and disposing Bitmap objects and thus not wasting memory.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111345/getting-image-dimensions-without-reading-the-entire-file)

Comment: @techno Did my answer helped you or you found your own solution then please let me know ?

Comment: Without creating image or bitmap object you can obtain width and height through shell property handler (`PKEY_Image_HorizontalResolution` and `PKEY_Image_HorizontalResolution` properties). This works for many formats, however the problem is that this is native API, not managed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems from the reference below that in the .NET 2.0 class library there is no functionality for it. Below code block should work,

There is no error checking or any other verification currently, and it usually does not read more that 6K from an image depending on the amount of the EXIF data.

### Sample Code

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace Test
{

    class Program
    {

        static bool GetJpegDimension(
            string fileName,
            out int width,
            out int height)
        {

            width = height = 0;
            bool found = false;
            bool eof = false;

            FileStream stream = new FileStream(
                fileName,
                FileMode.Open,
                FileAccess.Read);

            BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream);

            while (!found || eof)
            {

                // read 0xFF and the type
                reader.ReadByte();
                byte type = reader.ReadByte();

                // get length
                int len = 0;
                switch (type)
                {
                    // start and end of the image
                    case 0xD8: 
                    case 0xD9: 
                        len = 0;
                        break;

                    // restart interval
                    case 0xDD: 
                        len = 2;
                        break;

                    // the next two bytes is the length
                    default: 
                        int lenHi = reader.ReadByte();
                        int lenLo = reader.ReadByte();
                        len = (lenHi << 8 | lenLo) - 2;
                        break;
                }

                // EOF?
                if (type == 0xD9)
                    eof = true;

                // process the data
                if (len > 0)
                {

                    // read the data
                    byte[] data = reader.ReadBytes(len);

                    // this is what we are looking for
                    if (type == 0xC0)
                    {
                        width = data[1] << 8 | data[2];
                        height = data[3] << 8 | data[4];
                        found = true;
                    }

                }

            }

            reader.Close();
            stream.Close();

            return found;

        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(args[0]))
            {
                int w, h;
                GetJpegDimension(file, out w, out h);
                System.Console.WriteLine(file + ": " + w + " x " + h);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Reference: [Getting image dimensions without reading the entire file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/113323/468718)

### Update

[Reading Image Headers to Get Width and Height](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35978/Reading-Image-Headers-to-Get-Width-and-Height) will work for JPG, GIF, PNG and BMP image types.

Comment: @yogi As mentioned in the reference link: It is indeed working for `.jpg` or `.jpeg` images but may be not work properly for some older formats of `.bmp` images.

Comment: You can't have a generic solution for all file types with this kind of problem. You'll have to know how to read each file type, and decide which action you take according to the image type.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35978/Reading-Image-Headers-to-Get-Width-and-Height

Comment: Of course the `Bitmap` approach is restricted to file types .NET can read and understand, to it's not a general solution for all possible image files either.

Comment: @joey Article here mentions that it supports JPG, GIF, PNG and BMP image types. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35978/Reading-Image-Headers-to-Get-Width-and-Height

Answer (score 1):

This might help , using System.Drawing namspace

```
 System.Drawing.Image objImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Filepath);
            imageWidth = objImage.Width;
            imageHeight = objImage.Height;
```