# Getting image size from file in pixels

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to C# and building a small application as personal challenge. I am handling quite a few images in the application and have come to the point where I need to get the images' sizes to calculate their proportions. All of the images are in the .png format (my favorite image format for many reasons). How would I be able to return the width and height in pixels from the file?

Comment: Look at [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111345/getting-image-dimensions-without-reading-the-entire-file). You should get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

This code can help you:

```
BitmapImage bit = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\myImage.png"));
var h = bit.PixelHeight;
var w = bit.PixelWidth;
```