# Get Image dimensions in c# asp.net core (framework 4.6.1)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, image-manipulation

Any idea on how to get an image dimensions in asp.net core, knowing that System.Drawing.Image doesn't work on this version. This is how I am actually reading the image:

```
byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes("path_to_image");
return data;
```

i.e.: Can I find the Height and Width of an image in its byte[] representaion?

Any help in how to rotate the image is also welcome.

Comment: I think this may answer your question: [Getting image dimensions without reading the entire file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111345/getting-image-dimensions-without-reading-the-entire-file)

Comment: It depends on the type of image. What kind of images are you reading?

Comment: any type of image (jpeg, png, etc.) @Jean-François Beauchamp

Answer (score 1):

You want bytes 11-12 for Horizontal resolution, and 13-14 for Vertical resolution. Assuming you're talking about a JPEG image. And byte 10 gives you the unit type (dots per inch or dots per cm)

https://www.w3.org/Graphics/JPEG/jfif3.pdf